# Write dd image to NFS (AWS EFS)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, dd

I have a disk image (from dd).
Is it possible to save it to NFS (AWS EFS).

Of course I can mount it (loop) but it is over 1.5TB of small files and cp or rsync works very slowly.

I also tried by aws file sync, but unfortunately I get an error: `Input/output` error.

Hosts:
HOST A: Mounted image dd + nfs server
HOST B: Host with AWS file sync

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use EFS File Sync for the best performance:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/efs-file-sync-faster-file-transfer-to-amazon-efs-file-systems/

Comment: I tried file sync, but doesn't work (only I/O error, without details)

Comment: What's the full error? Also see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/troubleshooting.html#ioerror

Comment: Where can I find full error?
Info from file-sync console: https://imgur.com/a/tICQnck